# PyGTK: how to define the height of progressbar?

Tags: python, gtk

How to define the height of a progressbar in PyGTK?

```
barreProgression.pbar.set_text(texte + str(pourcent*100) + '%')
```

The text occupies two lines, and I would like one.

Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

Is the text wrapping because the widget isn't long enough to fit it all on one line? If so try setting the `hexpand` property to `True` so it gets any extra space horizontal space that's available.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your response, (and sorry for my bad english)
I have solved the problem by changing the file.log who "texte" var is read.
It was a problem of "\n" , newline. It's working now with:

```
fichierlog.write("\n" + repr(logsuiv))
```